# Real life example of superiority of struct over class in terms of GC .NET

Tags: c#, struct, garbage-collection

I worked on presentation about GC best practices in .NET. 
I created a few examples which illustrate influence to performance such practices as LargeObject polling, eliminating references between generation, right GC mode etc.
But when I tried to create example which shows superiority of structs vs classes I failed. Every peace of code which uses class\struct works the same way(I use "%time in GC" counter). I can create example with deference of consumed memory, but it looks like GC can deal with them, and there is no difference in %time in GC.
Could someone provide an example?

Here are a few examples:

```
while (true)
        {
            var collection = 
                Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000)
                .Select(x => new ModelStruct(x))
                .ToList();//Change to Model but no significant difference
            var result = collection.Average(x=>x.Id);
        }


while (true){
            Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 8), y =>
            {
                var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000)
                .Select(x => new Model(x))
                .ToList();//Change to Model but no significant difference
                var result = collection.Average(x => x.Id);
            });
        }

var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(x =>
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var model = new Model(x);
                return model;
            })
        ).ToArray();
var result = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).Average(x => x.HashCode);
```

Model is class\struct with 10+ Guids as a properties

Comment: Please show us the example you created.

Comment: Hopefully you'll be noting that any differences here should be *far* down the list when deciding on struct vs class.

Comment: This do? https://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html - note: you should **not** blindly just change from `class` to `struct` - you need to do a lot more than that, since they work very differently - naive changes will usually break your changes

Comment: Of course I understand that we shouldn't blindly change class to struct to solve a performance problem. I asking because I read dozen times about difference between stack and heap, struct and class and so on, but I can not see it with my own eyes.

Comment: Before you replicate a noticeable difference in *execution time*, try to replicate a noticeable difference in *the number of garbage collections triggered*. Once you have that down, you'll find ways to make the difference in execution time more pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing integers in multiple ways:

1. Put them in an `int[]` or `List<int>`. This is the struct version and will use `4*N` bytes of memory.
2. Store them boxed in an `object[]` or `List<object>`. This is the class version (using boxes as an easy way to do it, but you can also use `class { int x; }`. This will use `8*N+16*N+4*N` bytes of memory on x64. This is for the object references, object headers and int values.

Try iterating over that list and summing it, try calling `GC.Collect()` repeatedly in a loop. Use a large `N` so that the difference actually matters.

You will find large differences in memory usage, GC time and time to process the contents of the list.

Structs are not always faster but you asked for an example to highlight their possible advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a relatively large struct/class (10+ value-type fields), make a big array, then process the array with help of a method. When the item is passed to that method, it makes the compiler to copy the whole struct to the call stack, but in case of a class only the pointer is copied.
Also, if the array/list is a mix of items and nulls (or empty structs), you'd definitely have difference in memory consumption.